# Is it possible to save the sent email into the sent items folder using python?

Tags: python-2.7, smtplib

I want to sends an email but sent mail is empty. 
how to send an email, and then put a copy of it in the "Sent" mail folder.
what can i do?

Comment: https://www.example-code.com/python/smtp_sendWithCopyToSentFolder.asp

Comment: @JohnZwinck You should really add it as an answer if you know that the module works.

Comment: @code_byter: I didn't know, I'm new here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, its possible.

Basicaly you need to create an MIME email and then send it throug smptlib and than save it on Sent with imaplib.

[The official imaplib documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html)

[More detailed examples of using imaplib.](http://Here%20is%20an%20example:)

Here is an example:

```
import time
import ssl
import imaplib
import smtplib
import email

from email import encoders
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

class Mail:
    def __init__(self):
        # considering the same user and pass for smtp an imap
        self.mail_user = 'youruser@yourdomain.com'
        self.mail_pass = 'pass'
        self.mail_host = 'mail.yourdomain'


    def send_email(self, to, subject, body, path, attach):
        message = MIMEMultipart()
        message["From"] = self.mail_user
        message["To"] = to
        message["Subject"] = subject
        message.attach(MIMEText(body, "plain"))

        with open(path + attach, "rb") as attachment:
            part = MIMEBase("application", "octet-stream")
            part.set_payload(attachment.read())
        encoders.encode_base64(part)

        part.add_header(
            "Content-Disposition",
            "attachment; filename= \"" + attach + "\"",
        )
        message.attach(part)
        text = message.as_string()

        context = ssl.create_default_context()
        with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(self.mail_host, 465, context=context) as server:
            result = server.login(self.mail_user, self.mail_pass)
            server.sendmail(self.mail_user, to, text)

        imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(self.mail_host, 993)
        imap.login(self.mail_user, self.mail_pass)
        imap.append('INBOX.Sent', '\\Seen', imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), text.encode('utf8'))
        imap.logout()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    m = Mail()
    m.send_email('someone@somewhere.com', 'Hello', 'Its just a test!', 'c:\\', 'test.pdf')
```

Comment: with pdf (only) attachments, is it possible to have “pdf”,”pdf” rather than "application", "octet-stream"?