# How to put emails in sent folder with django send_mail()?

Tags: django, email

I am using django's simple mail send function.

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail(
    'Subject here',
    'Here is the message.',
    'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'],
    fail_silently=False,
)
```

How can I use this to put the sent emails in the mailbox sent folder?

Comment: You mean in local for testing ?

Answer (score 2):

I had success with the method below, but I'm using Django's EmailMultiAlternatives. Basically the same should work with the 'send_mail' - function, too. Depending on your email connection you may have to change a few details of IMAP.

Documentation of pythons imaplib:
https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/imaplib.html

Further information about sending emails with django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/email/

Required modules:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.conf import settings
import imaplib, time
```

Code that sends the mail:

```
#Send email
email = EmailMultiAlternatives(
                    subject=subject, body=body_text, 
                    from_email=from_email, to=email_to, 
                    reply_to=['****@****.ch'],
                    headers={})
#Attaches html version of email
email.attach_alternative(message_html, "text/html")
#Attaches image
email.attach(signature())
#Sends email
email.send()
```

Prepares the email message we have just sent. Will be used afterwards to copy the email in the sent folder.

```
#Loads the email message to append it afterwards with IMAP
message = str(email.message())
```

Places the email in the sent folder.

```
#Creates a copy of the email in the sent folder
imap = imaplib.IMAP4(settings.EMAIL_HOST)
imap.starttls()
imap.login(settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, settings.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD)
imap.append('INBOX.Sent', '\\SEEN', imaplib.Time2Internaldate(time.time()), message.encode())  
imap.logout()
```

Implemented in one of my projects using django 2.2.9 and python 3.8.1.

My own solution was inspired by this post: [Is it possible to save the sent email into the sent items folder using python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44823746/is-it-possible-to-save-the-sent-email-into-the-sent-items-folder-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can send mail to file with this config : [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/email/#file-backend)

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_FILE_PATH = '/tmp/app-messages' # change this to a proper location
```